# Function formula doesn't work it supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this formula and I couldn't understand why it gives an incorrect result. Here is the code:

```
//gebder 0=male 1=female

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#met_inputs').hide();
$('#unit_std').prop('checked', true);
var standardUnits = true;
$('input[name="unit"]:radio').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "met") {
        standardUnits = false;
        $('#standard_inputs').hide();
        $('#met_inputs').show();
    } else {
        standardUnits = true;
        $('#standard_inputs').show();
        $('#met_inputs').hide();
    }
});
var BMI = 0;
var RMR = 0;
$("#cal_btn").click(function() {
    if (standardUnits) {
        BMI = BMIStd();
    } else {
        BMI = BMIMet();
    }


    BMI = BMI.toFixed(1);

    RMR = getRMR().toFixed(1);

    //make all inputs black
    $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'black');
    });


    if (isNaN(BMI) || isNaN(RMR)) {
        $('#results').html('<h2>Please fill-up the required field.</h2>');
        $('#results').css('color', 'red');

    //make blank inputs red
        $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            }
        });
        return;
    } else {
        $('#results').css('color', 'black');
    }

    $("#results").html("<h2>Your BMI is " + BMI+"</h2>");

    if (BMI > 25) {
        $('#results').append("You are <b>above</b> the Normal BMI Range. Lose at least <b>" +    getLoss().toFixed(1) + "</b> to reach Normal BMI Range. Read these <a href='http://www.calculator-bmi.com/category/how-to-lose-weight/'>posts that will help you to lose weight. </a>");

 //$('#suggestion').append("<br><br>Your Resting Metabolic Rate (<i>Calories your body use</i>) is = <b>"+RMR+"</b>. This will be your guide if you want to lose, gain or maintain your weight.");
    } else if (BMI < 25 && BMI > 18.5) {
        $('#results').append("You weight is great! Just maintain what you're doing. Read more on <a href='http://www.calculator-bmi.com/category/how-to-maintain-weight/'>How to Maintain Weight</a> for optimal health.");
    } else if (BMI <= 18.4) {
        $('#results').append("You are <b>below</b> the Normal BMI Range. Gain at least <b>" + getGain().toFixed(1) + "</b> to reach Normal BMI Range. Read these <a href='http://www.calculator-bmi.com/category/how-to-gain-weight/'>posts on How to Gain Weight. </a>");

    }
    $('#suggestion').html("Your <b>Basal Metabolic Rate</b> (Calories your body use) is <b>" + RMR + "</b>. This will be your guide if you want to lose, gain or maintain your weight.");
});


function BMIMet() {
    var weight = parseFloat($("#met_weight").val());
    var height = parseFloat($("#met_height").val());
    return weight * 10000 / Math.pow(height, 2);
}

function BMIStd() {
    var weight = parseFloat($("#std_weight").val());
    var height = parseFloat($("#std_height_ft").val()) * 12 + parseFloat($("#std_height_in").val());
    return weight * 703 / Math.pow(height, 2);
}

function getRMR() {
    var weight = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var age = parseFloat($('#age').val());
    if (standardUnits) {
        weight = parseFloat($("#std_weight").val());
        height = parseFloat($("#std_height_ft").val()) * 12 + parseFloat($("#std_height_in").val());
    } else {
        weight = LbtoKg(parseFloat($("#met_weight").val()));
        height = IntoCm(parseFloat($("#met_height").val()));
    }



    if (getGender() === '0') {
        return (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height)) - (6.8 * age);
    } else {
        return 655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age);
    }
}

function getLoss() {
    if (standardUnits) {
        weight = parseFloat($("#std_weight").val());
        height = parseFloat($("#std_height_ft").val()) * 12 + parseFloat($("#std_height_in").val());
        return weight - (25 / 703) * height * height;
    } else {
        weight = parseFloat($("#met_weight").val());
        height = parseFloat($("#met_height").val());
        return weight - (25 / 10000) * height * height;
    }
}

function getGain() {
    if (standardUnits) {
        weight = parseFloat($("#std_weight").val());
        height = parseFloat($("#std_height_ft").val()) * 12 + parseFloat($("#std_height_in").val());
        return ((18.5 / 703) * height * height) - weight;
    } else {
        weight = parseFloat($("#met_weight").val());
        height = parseFloat($("#met_height").val());
        return ((18.5 / 10000) * height * height) - weight;
    }
}

function LbtoKg(val) {
    return parseFloat(val) * 2.20462;
}

function IntoCm(val) {
    return parseFloat(val) * 0.393701;
}

function getGender() {
    return $('select[name="gender"]').val();
}



});
```

Here is the right formula.

Women: BMR = 655 + ( 4.35 x weight in pounds ) + ( 4.7 x height in inches ) – ( 4.7 x age in years )

Men: BMR = 66 + ( 6.23 x weight in pounds ) + ( 12.7 x height in inches ) – ( 6.8 x age in year )

When I use the calculator, it shows an incorrect result. I don't know how to fix it. And I am not that good in coding. I hope someone could help.

Here's the part of that code contains the formula..

```
    if (getGender() === '0') {
        return (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height)) - (6.8 * age);
    } else {
        return 655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age);
    }
```

Comment: what is the using language?

Comment: What do you mean "using language" ? Do you mean jquery or something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is JavaScript, specifically jQuery, and I have edited the post as such. If I'm wrong, someone please re-edit the post to add the correct tags.

Comment: yeah. it's a javascript. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, I suggest adding a tag or two to indicate what language your code is in; this will attract people who are familiar with that language, which will get you better answers. It will also save you time because nobody will have to ask what language you're working with.

Comment: Why do the height and weight multipliers in your JS differ from those in the "right" formula? E.g. 13.7*weight vs 6.23*weight.

Comment: incorrect result? can give some example?

Comment: Oh my! That fixed the problem! I used a formula for metric system in which should have been for standard system. Thank you!